# MS SQL How to select clients where last N records are the same

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that is consisted of ClientID, ActionDate, Action and Result.

I need to select distinct Clients which have ONLY the specific Action/Result combo in the given date range.

To illustrate:

1. I need distinct clientIDs whose last 5 Action/Result are Call/NoAnswer.
2. I need distinct clientIDs who have ONLY Call/NoAnswer in the last 30 days.

Thanks

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: What is the primary key of the table? Also, last 5 including or excluding this?

Comment: I am having troubles setting the "Where" clause. If i set it to the specific Action/Result, it will only count those actions. The logic of the query which i should set up is not clearing up in my head.
Maybe to have a few sub-selects, which would pick Top1, Top2-Top1, Top3-(Top2-top1), etc, which should all be the same. I am sure there is more elegant way, but i am too novice to be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

```
select ClientID from
(
select 
  ClientID,
  Action,
  Result,
  row_number() over (partition by ClientID order by ActionDate desc) as num
from ClientActions
) T -- the latest 5 action/result
where rnum <= 5
group by ClientID
having MAX(case when Action='Call' and Result = 'NoAnswer' then 0 else 1 end) = 0
```

2.

```
select ClientID
from ClientActions
where DATEDIFF(DAY, ActionDate, GETDATE()) <= 30
group by ClientID
having MAX(case when Action='Call' and Result = 'NoAnswer' then 0 else 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: The 1st one works like a charm, thank you. I have to analyze it now and try to understand it fully, for future reference.

As for the second one, this will take Clients that have only the last action like that, right? What if i want all actions in the last month to be Call/NoAnswer? I guess i would have to remove MAX?

Comment: @Peraklo, the second query with MAX should take Clients who have all actions in the last month equal to Call/NoAnswer. you can easily test it